# How to add user to list of Remote desktop users on remote machine using Powershell?

Tags: remote-desktop, powershell

I wan't to make a script that connects to remote machine and add specific domain user to list of users who can connect to that machine using Remote Desktop.

How to do that using Powershell?

Answer (score 1):

I would actually suggest you setup a Group Policy to add the users to the local "Remote Desktop Users" group.  That way you don't have to worry about the computers being on and if the computer gets redeployed the group membership gets applied automatically.

Comment: I agree with Scott but if you did want to pursue the Powershell route then [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/03/11/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-add-a-domain-user-to-a-local-group.aspx) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I need a Powershell script, to easy enable users access to some machines. I'm not an administrator, so I can't influence group polices.
Anyway I found a workaround using psexec from SysInternals and NET command. Works well.